# How to config composer with proxy'

Tags: php, proxy, composer-php

First of all I apologize for my English and thank you in advance for any response. I was reading several solutions about the configuration of composer behind a proxy but the truth is that I still have problems.
Already create the environment variables

```
HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI = false
HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI = false
HTTP_PROXY = my_http_proxy: proxy_port
HTTPS_PROXY = my_https_proxy: proxy_port
```

But I get the following problem when I use composer:
    The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:     failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
    https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was     loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The 'http://packagist.org/p/provider-    2013%24c23e27d4ef97dede5bbe3fe1d348566
bd1a463ccbe767186c51beab5436c9bad.json' URL could not be accessed:     HTTP/1.1
400 Bad Request
```

Again thank you for any help and time you can give me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your SO need define variables in lower case, or maybe you need define user and password for your proxy.

Another thing in my case was I didn't set http_proxy variable with "http://" part like below:

http_proxy = http://username:password@ip:port 
and 
https_proxy = http://username:password@ip:port